# Unit Testing a Secure URL

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In our application we are generating a secure URL which is sent to the customers email. Once, they click the URL they are redirected to our site where they login to the website.

Initially we were exposing a custom action "DEMOTESTURL" which was exposed to the Unit Test project. Unfortunately, we cannot do that in production and was wondering how can the Test project (separate assembly) can access the generated URL.

Comment: Show us some sample code that helps illustrate your problem.

Comment: What process generates the URL?  It sounds like the test should invoke that process to get the URL before invoking the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a unit test, but rather an integration test. To the point:

If the URL is dynamically generated, you need to treat it as such and save it to file/database or expose its value as service.

If it is a static string you can embed it in a test library configuration file.

Comment: Yes it is integration test!